# How to Set Message ID via MQJavaClient

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to set custom string as Message ID via MQJavaClient what I have done so for is below:

1. String I want to place in message id

   ```
   example :92f5fd96300e8dce
   ```
2. Get hex number from online[codebeautify.org]

   ```
   example:39326635666439363330306538646365
   ```
3. In Java client code as below

   ```
   String str = "39326635666439363330306538646365";  
   sendmsg.messageId = str.getBytes();
   ```

When try to print messageid, it is giving some other results

```
sendmsg.messageId : [B@1b40d5f0
```

Still needed messageid is not populated with MQ Message.

Please help on this to set custom message ID for MQ Message.

> Roger / Josh  26 dec 2017

**Need help on this**
If you need/want to store your own message id or transaction id then use a message property or the Correlation ID field of the MQMD - just don't use the MQMD's Message ID.
In our application , we are using both msgid/txnid and correlation  id.
msgid/txnid will different for each transaction(should be same for request an response).
correlation  id will same across all transactions.

**What am trying now?**
1.System A and System B talking via MQs
2.Now suddenly System B is responding with different format as response and System A is not able perform its operations.
3.Now my job is to simulate System B response via java client.
4.I found in our application we use both msgid and correl id
5.I am done with correl id and its reading perfectly by System A.
6.But this msgid is NOT populating via java client and showing as msgid as null in logs.

Comment: It seems you are printing a byte array as a string, to get back your original string try printing it after converting back to String like: new String(sendmsg.messageId); And why do you need the hex encoded part? And by the way I agree with Roger, the message id is not for sending (meta)data.

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea, very bad idea to generate your own Message ID in IBM MQ.  MQ will automatically generate a unique Message ID for the message when your application issues an MQPUT and/or MQPUT1.

If you need/want to store your own message id or transaction id then use a message property or the Correlation ID field of the MQMD - just don't use the MQMD's Message ID.